# Publishing selection in eclipse RCP

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, selection

I'm writing an RCP application plug-in. I want to make a set of objects the global selection from a IHandler but this can be triggered from other views out of my control - it is possible that these do not have an ISelectionProvider.

Is it possible to publish a selection to the eclipse selection service without going through some view site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think, its possible. The best you could do is to provide the selection through a view site, and then listen only to the selection of your own view (by creating a special selection listener).